# How to write request sql with symbol id

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.2

i want to found an user in table `users` with id like :

```
<%= @user = User.find_by_sql("SELECT users . * FROM users WHERE id = [:id] ")%>
```

But i have an exception :

`Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[:id]' at line 1: SELECT users . * FROM users WHERE id = [:id]`

Comment: Probably u misplaced " in Syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the [`documentation`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Querying.html#method-i-find_by_sql):

```
find_by_sql(sql, binds = [])
```

Wrap query with binds in an array:

```
=> User.find_by_sql(["select users.email from users where email = :q and first_name = :a", {q: 'foo', a: 'bar'}])
```

Comment: Return the same error : Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':q' at line 1: SELECT users . * FROM users WHERE id = :q

Comment: <%= @user = User.find_by_sql("SELECT users . * FROM users WHERE id = :q", {q: :id})%>

Comment: it should be `User.find_by_sql(["SELECT users .* FROM users WHERE id = :q", {q: 1}])` The second argument its a hash `{ q: 'user_id' }` e.g. `{ q: 1 }`

Comment: Thats okay but i want to retrieve the id in the symbol :id

Comment: __i want to retrieve the id in the symbol :id__ what's you mean?

Comment: The symbol :id contains the id of the user i want to find

Comment: symbol in ruby is immutable, you can assing value to the symbol, this not wrok `:id = 1`. You can make hash like this `{ id: 1 }`  and use it like `User.find_by_sql(["SELECT users .* FROM users WHERE id = :id", {id: 1}])`

Comment: Ok, so when i do this : `<%= user = User.find(params[:id]).inspect%>` i found the user corresponding but when i want to do user.name it return `undefined method 'name' for #<String:0x007f12d84997a0>`

Comment: @Sleed because `inspect` method returns string representation. `user = User.find(params[:id]).inspect` assign sting to the `user` variable.

Comment: In my view : `<%= user = User.find(params[:id]).inspect%>`
`<h1>Liste des incidents de <%= user.name %> <%= current_user.surname%></h1>`

Comment: i can't understand how it's related to the main question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<%= @user = User.find_by_sql("SELECT users . * FROM users WHERE id = "[:id] 
)%>
```

Comment: Return this : no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

Comment: replace [:id] with [:id].to_i

Comment: Return again : no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

Comment: what is the datatype of symbol id??